# XPath - verify contents of @title

Tags: xpath, fitnesse

Background info of my question:
I am working in FitNesse, and usually I can use CSS selectors to find and verify the elements I want. However, in this case I need to check a `@title` attribute through XPath, and I'm having trouble doing so.

My FitNesse scenario is something like this:

```
| ensure | do | verifyText | on | !-xpath statement to the @title attribute here-! | with | @the_title_I_expect
```

This means that I need to find an XPath to the @title element to verify it, not have the @title with content in my XPath expression.

Can someone help me out?

Example:

```
<th id="scollTable.titleRow.column2" title="**This is my title**" colspan="1" scope="col" class="detailTableHeader">Some text here I don't care about</th>
```

I would like to check the text 'This is my title' for validity.
Any pointers? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `//*[@id="scollTable.titleRow.column2"  and @title="This is my title"]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know about the 'and' addition, but I would like to verify the content of my @title separately. Meaning, when I would like to check the contents of the 'th', I would probably check //*[@id=" scollTable.titleRow.column2"]/text() --> I would like to do the same for the @title; refer to it and check the text with what I expect it to be. Is there another way besides using 'and'?

Comment: `//*[@title="This is my title"]`

Comment: I think I might not have been clear enough with my question, apoligies for that.. I'm working in a FitNesse scenario, in which I do a 'verifyText' action: | ensure | do | verifyText | on | !-//*[@id="scollTable.titleRow.column2]-! | with | @iwanttocheckthetitle | ----> I thought with asking for how to validate the content of title I would get the answer I need, but apparently I don't.. I will see if I can edit my question to make it more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Xebium? I believe they have (actually the Selenium 1 API they use has) a command `verifyAttribute` that you can use to check attributes instead of the text of the element. (A quick google gave me [this example page](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2013/07/selenium-ide-verifyattribute-and.html).)

So I believe your row would become:

`| ensure | do | verifyAttribute | on | xpath=//th[@id='scollTable.titleRow.column2']@title| with | !-**This is my title**-!|`

P.S. I'm not very familiar with Xebium but I believe you can rewrite such a line to a `check` instead of an `ensure` so that your test report will show you the actual title when the test fails, instead of just reporting 'failed'.

Comment: Amazing... It works.. Can't believe the solution was so simple... I did rewrite it to 'check is' instead of 'ensure do', but my test is returning the results now. Thanks a lot, you've really been a great help. And @splash58, thanks to your time and effort as well, and again apologies for not asking the right question right away!